# PHP- What is the best way to pass NULL to a function?

Tags: php

I have a function that I am trying to pass a NULL value to:

```
function test($this=null, $that=null) {

  if ($this) {
    // Do something
  }

  if ($that) {
    // Do something else
  }

}
```

So, if I am trying to pass a value only for `$that`, I can do:

```
$that = 100;

this('',$that);
```

But is the `''` the best way to pass NULL to a function?

Comment: Why not just pass `null`?

Comment: Why not use `false` rather than `null`?

Comment: false is boolean value it is not the same

Comment: Why downvote this question? It looks legit to me

Comment: @OskarD90 It's quite unclear - "how do I pass null to a function".... just pass null?  If there's more to the question, it's not spelt out very well.

Comment: @Robert I know but it seems as if `null` could be replaced in the above question and auther doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, judging by the comments here others are also undecided as to the best practice.

Comment: Btw, don’t use `$this` as a variable name in PHP.

Comment: @JamesThorpe there are multiple ways of doing this. test(null, null) or test() both work. He asks which way is the best, presumably he doesn't know about all possibilities. I don't think this is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `null`:

```
$that = 100;

test(null,$that);
```

Comment: If you want to pass null to the second argument, you can just leave it out like so: test($this). Or if you want to pass null arguments to both, just test() will have the same functionality as test(null, null)

Comment: ^ This works because the function has optional parameters with default values

Answer (score 1):

The best way to pass a `null` value to a PHP function is the following:

```
someFunction(null);
```

And then, to check if `null` was passed *inside* the function, use either `$param === null` or `is_null($param)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find difference between an empty string and null. This is not the same.

the best way is to use

```
 test(null, $that);
```

If you use `===` operator you will see the difference